# How to convert unix time into date in druid or apache-druid

Tags: sql, presto, druid

I want to use `date_diff` function in `@druid`. Where my input will be to `unix_timestamp`.

`Unix_timestamp = 1597689016000`

I want this to be converted into a timestamp where I can find the difference between two times.

Also please tell me, what is fiction to difference of both timestamps.

Comment: Is this Presto-related?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the from_unixtime function, it expects seconds, and your timestamp is in milliseconds so divide by thousand:

```
from_unixtime(CAST(Unix_timestamp /1000 as BIGINT))
```

Sorry just saw it was in Druid, that shold work in presot. In Druid there is this function:

```
MILLIS_TO_TIMESTAMP(Unix_timestamp )
```

Comment: How do I convert time into epoch if I use GROUP BY together with TIME_FLOOR ?